# Operator "===" doesn't evaluate correctly when used in an object as it should php

Tags: php, class, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to loop through an array assigned to an object. The function **entity_products_check()** must compare the submitted product to an array of pre-held values from a database.
The **foreach loop** must evaluate to true in the provided test example. However, for reasons I cannot understand the **===** operator returns **empty** (i.e. null) and XAMPP evaluates it to false. For some bizarre reason this occurs only if one checks for the first value. For any other result it executes correctly.
I do not understand why this happens?

```
 $entity=array("products"=>array("machine", "lollipop"));
 class Borrowing_Cost
 {
    public array $entity;
    public array $item;
    public array $borrowing;
    public function __construct($entity, $item, $borrowing)
    {

        $this->entity = $entity;
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->borrowing = $borrowing;
    }

    public function entity_products_check($arg){
        $is_item = "";                

        **foreach ($this->entity["products"] as $value){           
            if($value === $arg){
                $is_item = "true";
            } else {
                $is_item = "false";
            }
        }**

        return $is_item;
    }
 }
 $borr = new Borrowing_Cost($entity, $item, $borrowing);
 echo $borr->entity_products_check("machine") . "<br>";
```

Comment: `===` never returns `empty` (what is empty in comparisons?) or `NULL`. It returns `true` or `false`, nothing else.  The second thing is your loop, in `$is_item` will be the last value only. For example, in foreach will be 10 items, 3rd will be true, but function returns false (because last one is false).

Comment: You should turn error reporting on, your code generates several.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you compare every item against the value you are looking for, so after it finds it, it will still go onto the next item and set the flag to `false`.

This code sets to `false` at the start and only ever flags it `true` when found and then stops...
public function entity_products_check($arg){
$is_item = "false";

```
    foreach ($this->entity["products"] as $value){
        if($value === $arg){
            $is_item = "true";
            break;
        }
    }

    return $is_item;
}
```

Or you could use `in_array()` to check if the value is in the array for you...

```
public function entity_products_check($arg){
    return in_array($arg, $this->entity["products"])
        ? "true" : "false";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was staring me in the face. Thank you.